# How to make different tabs dynamically according to requirements?

Tags: android, tabs

In Food Panda App when i clicked on different display restaurants. Then show different tabs according to there items.

My question is, how to make different tabs according to restaurant different items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("THE NAME YOU WANT"));
```

Comment: kindly explain it with details.